# TelosB library sensor Contiki

Tags: sensors, contiki

I'm new on langage C and Contiki.
I'm a student (French) so sorry for my little english.

I went through a lot of GitHub for help but i didn't found ...
So i'm here.

I try to make my PIR motion sensor (SEN0171) on my TelobsB but i don't know where to put the wires.
In the code .c to, i don't know how and where to "initialize" PINs.
I have to creat a Makefile to...

I have tried some things but always errors ...

Can you halp me please?
Thank's a lot

PS : i put a photo of my Telos and PIR sensor.
thx

[TelosB and more](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUXel.jpg)

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. This question is currently too broad. Please look at the [help] to learn how to ask a good question. Then share what you have done so far. We need a [mcve] to give you help on your code.

Comment: i don't know how to do the code ... that's my problem :/